# capybara webkit flakiness claiming page has no content?

Tags: capybara-webkit

I've got a rails app with devise, and have an incredibly straight forward spec demonstrating the ability to sign out a user:

```
sign_in user
visit root_path

within('.nav-links') do
  page.find('.icon.logout').click
end

within('form') do
  expect(page).to have_field 'user_username'
  expect(page).to have_field 'user_password'
end
```

This intermittently fails, claiming that there's no form element on the page...

Out of desperation, I changed the spec to actually look (and wait) for content:

```
expect(page).to have_content 'MY FOOTER'

within('form') do
  expect(page).to have_field 'user_username'
  expect(page).to have_field 'user_password'
end
```

And I get:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content 'MY FOOTER'
   expected to find text "MY FOOTER" in ""
```

Which is telling me there is no content at all on the page????????????????????

What?

This failure happens every 5 or so test runs.  Does anyone have any idea why this sort of thing would happen?  How is it that signing out every now and then results in a blank page?  I can't ever get this to fail while watching it execute in the browser with selenium / chromedriver.  It only seems to be failing with webkit.

Comment: Try increasing Capybara.default_max_wait_time and see if that improves things

Comment: I bumped it up to 6 seconds, and get the same results unfortunately.

Comment: if you can create a small example project that exhibits the issue I'll take a look, otherwise I'm out of guesses.

Comment: Well, I have been doing some more experimenting.  It appears that when this happens, capybara is rendering a blank page.  Here's a screenshot I took prior to the failure:  http://tinyurl.com/pm3tlfm

Comment: And I can get this to happen every time by using a seed...  So it has something to do with test ordering.

Comment: and of course this passes with non-headless drivers, so I can't ever see it happen.  It somehow means capybara-webkit is not handling redirects properly

Comment: Interesting -- so when you've set the seed what is the previous test doing?

Comment: @TomWalpole it's just opened a modal for a terms of service dialog and clicking cancel on it.  Cancel is an anchor tag which redirects to '/sign_out' ... total nonsense.  I am opening an issue with capybara-webkit

Comment: here is the issue --> https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/841